# in kde How to get an icon that show the currant layout language

Tags: keyboard-layout

This is not for KDE
System Settings → Text Entry → Lower left corner: [v] Show current input source in the menu bar
How to get the language icon to show the current language in ubuntu 14.04 kde?keyboard layout indicator icon on KDE doesn't show the current language

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the bottom panel 
(it is usually at the bottom unless you have changed) - add widgets - and there choose keyboard layout indicator widget.

Comment: Thanks
I wonder how I missed finding it in the long search I did.